# Ошибка передачи параметра из шаблона во View в Django

Tags: django

Получаю ошибку при попытке отобразить в шаблоне запись из БД по ссылке из другого шаблона.

В база данных есть некоторые записи, которые необходимо редактировать.

Перед этим список записей БД выводится в шаблон, каждая запись имеет ссылку для своего редактирования.

Передача параметра из шаблона во View происходит классически:

```
<a href="{% url 'entryview' entry.id %}"> {{entry}}</a>
```

URL.py:

```
urlpatterns = [url(r'^entryview/(?P<pk>\d+)/', app.views.entryview, name='entryview'),]
```

view.py:

```
def entryview(request, pk):
    entry = Entry.objects.get(id = pk)

    return(request,'app/entryview.html',         
        {   'staff': request.user.staff, 'entry': entry, 'pk': pk,
            'year': datetime.now().year,        
        })
```

В итоге получаю ошибку несуществующего атрибута для переданного кортежа.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чём здесь может быть ошибка??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В пропущенном имени функции

```
return render(request,'app/entryview.html', ...
```